# Azure Devops deployment failure: The 'Performing deployment' operation conflicts with the pending 'Performing deployment' operation

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create a devops pipeline to deploy an azure function.
Each time I try I get the error:

```
BadRequest: The 'Performing deployment' operation conflicts with the 
pending 'Performing deployment' operation started at 2022-08-16T13:01:47.6881726Z.  
Please retry operation later.
```

I have waited 2  hours and still get this error.
In the resource group, i cannot see any pending deployments, only failed deployments.

Also, get-AzDeployment cmdlet returns no data so i cant find any deployments that may be blocking.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Could you elaborate how you created the CI Pipeline - using which method CLI, YAML Code, ...?

Comment: I have an arm template for the function app, exported.from azure portal. I've tried tondeplybthis a number of ways, firstly in a release pipeline created using the DevOps gui. Secondly as a custom template.innthr azure portal. In both cases I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

The message usually indicates that there is another pending deployment operation that is ongoing and it would prevent the new deployment. However, you don't see any results from running the get-AzDeployment cmdlet. Additionally, you can run the Get-AzDeploymentOperation cmdlet as it lists all the operations that were part of a deployment to help you identify and give more information about the exact operations that failed for a particular deployment.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azdeploymentoperation?view=azps-8.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was due to exporting the arm template from the portal.
For some reason the portal included a bunch of "deployments" in the template. These deployments which had already run were clashing when I ran the template.

I've no idea why it includes old deployments in the template but deleting them resolved that particular issue.